# librrd_th.so in rrdtool 1.7.0 under CentOS 8

Tags: compiler-errors, rrdtool

I'm trying to recompile some old software that uses rrdtool under CentOS 8.  The application is looking for librrd_th.so.  The rrdtool with CentOS 8 is 1.7.0 and I have the -devel package installed too.

It looks like rrdtool-1.4.8 under CentOS 7 has it.  So I'm trying to figure out if between 1.4.8 and 1.7.0 it was deprecated in RRD Tool, or if its a strange issue with the package build.  I've tried to recompile 1.7.0 (don't know exactly what I'm doing) and don't think it gets built anymore.

If its no longer part of the package, any suggestions for adapting code that is getting build errors with things like "undefined reference to `rrd_get_context'"

Thanks for any ideas at all.

Andy

Comment: So re-reading a quick comment I was given, "librrd.so itself is not threadsafe"  So is it that librrd.so is not thread safe, but librrd_th.so is thread safe?  Or code was found to be not thread safe at all and thus the librrd_th.so was removed from newer versions?

Comment: The librrd_th was the old (slower) threadsafe library.  The latest version of rrdtool is threadsafe, so does not need this alternative library.  Supposedly they are compatible but you might find some thing missing.

Answer (score 0):

Digging through issues on github and then a pull request lead me to this

https://github.com/oetiker/rrdtool-1.x/pull/667

"Do I understand correctly, that all this functions are guaranteed to be thread-safe disregarding what is said at https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/prog/rrdthreads.en.html ?"

oetiker replie:
rrdtool 1.7 is threadsafe yes, this document only applies to older versions of rrdtool ... the _th library is also not available with 1.7 anymore.